# custom AppBar not showing flutter

Tags: flutter

i create new application i try to make my appBar showing but it's not working ,

```
class Myappbar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Text(
        'text',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement preferredSize
  Size get preferredSize => throw UnimplementedError();
}
```

**home screen** :

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: Myappbar(),
      body: Center(child: Text("home")),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustumBottomNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

i m new in flutter , please help me , thank you.

Comment: implement the `get`ter which is marked for TODO. Currently it is throwing an error.

Answer (score 1):

change this line ->

```
class Myappbar extends PreferredSize {
final double height;

Myappbar({this.height = kToolbarHeight});

@override
Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);
```